# Drop down description or expandable view

Tags: java, android, view

So I want to create something like this:
click the `+` button than a view appears underneath it and displays buttons
then when the `X` is pressed it goes away. I found the Spinner class but that seams to provide a list not a separate view. Any recommendations to how I could accomplish this? The app shown in the pictures is Go SMS
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html